# Two Activities in the same view

Tags: android, android-activity

In my application, I have two activities. One for display comments, and one for add comments.

In Landscape, I want to display the two activities on the screen, the comments at left and the form at right.

Do you have an idea to do this ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you have to use fragment

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html

Comment: Use fragment instead of 2 Activity.

Comment: find here, http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Yes, but in portrait, the two activities are different...

Comment: @Tom59 you can specialize your layout for portrait so it will look differently than for landscape

Comment: That's a job for Fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you need to do is to move your `Activity's` logic to `Fragments`. Then create new layout for landscape mode that will contain both of that `Fragments`.

Just follow [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and you will see how to do this. The [Design Philosophy](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Design) part fully describes what you want to do.